# How to plot RegionPlot in loglog scale?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

Consider some function `f[x,y]`. I need to plot region of values `f[x,y]>=1`, with normal scaling for y and with log log scaling for `x`. I.e., something like `LogLogPlot[f[x,y],{x,x1,x2}]` for fixed `y`. However, I don't know the command for `RegionPlot[f[x,y]>=1,{x,x1,x2},{y,y1,y2}]` allowing me to plot `x` in log log scale.

Can anyone help me please?

Precisely, I need to plot the region

```
ldecay[mN_, U_] = 0.625/(U*mN^6);
f[mN_,U_]=3.6*10^9*U*(Exp[-100*Sqrt[2]/(ldecay[mN, U])] - 
   Exp[-(100*Sqrt[2] + 45)/(ldecay[mN, U])])
```

for $10^{-9} < U < 10^{-1}$ and $1<mN<20$, with $mN$ axis being in log log scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

manually work in terms of the log:

```
RegionPlot[f[mN, 10^logu] >= 1, {logu, -9, -1}, {mN, 1, 20}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, 
                   {{#, N[10^#]} & /@ Range[-9, -1],  None}},
    PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Edit. LogLog plot:

```
RegionPlot[
 f[10^lmN, 10^logu] >= 1, {logu, -9, -1}, {lmN, 0, Log[10, 20]}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, FrameLabel -> {"Log10 u", "Log10 mN" }]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But this is not exactly what I need. The problem is that instead of U on x axis I'm dealing with log U variable. This is crucial when I need to interpret the values of U (say, for "simple" U = 5 I need to find "complicated" log U 0.69 on x axis). This problem is absent when considering LogLogPlot.

Comment: just remove the `FrameTicks` option, you will get `-9,-8,..-1` for the x axis ( "log u" )

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please also tell me why when plotting with axes {mN, 1, 20}, {logu, -9, -1} instead of {logu, -9, -1}, {mN, 1, 20} the values on mN axis aren't displayed?

Comment: If you are manually specifying `FrameTicks` its easy to get it wrong and end up with no ticks. Usually leave the `FrameTicks` option out until you get the plot the way you want, then add that if needed.