# Changing the frameticks

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

Following [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169295/54258), I want a region plot in log-log scale as

```
f[x_, y_] = x^2 - y;

RegionPlot[f[10^lx, 10^ly] <= 400, {lx, 0, 5}, {ly, 0, 5}]
```

However, along the y-axis I want  `FrameTicks`  to be $10^5$, $10^3$ and so on, rather than $5,3,..$. How should this be done? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:
First, let us define the ticks of the y-axis:

```
f[x_] := {x, (HoldForm[10]^Evaluate[x])}
lst = Map[f, Range[5]]
```

[image]

Now, let us plot:

```
RegionPlot[f[10^lx, 10^ly] <= 400, {lx, 0, 5}, {ly, 0, 5}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{lst, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

with the following effect:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: How will I modify it if the plot ranges on the x and y-axes are different, say 0 to 5 on the y-axis and 7 to 23 on the x-axis?

Comment: I have solved it. For example - 

f1[x_] := {x, (HoldForm[10]^Evaluate[x])} ;
lsty = Map[f1, Range[5]]; lstx = Map[f1, Range[1, 3]] ;
f[x_, y_] = x - y; RegionPlot[
 f[10^lx, 10^ly] <= 40, {lx, 1, 3}, {ly, 0, 5}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{lsty, None}, {lstx, None}}]

Comment: Recommend `f[x_] := {x, (HoldForm[10]^x)}; lst = Map[f, Range[0, 5]]`